# Regex R programming

Tags: regex, r

I am very new to R programming and my question would seem silly.

Below is a character vector in R.

```
longString <- "ggstyle<-function(inputFile {tableMedian=inputFile#plotstyleroutine#thislinesolvestheproblemifthemedianofevennumberofdaysistakenbytakingthevectornumberdayMedVec=round(length(unique(tableMedian$day))/2,0)dayMed=as.numeric(unique(tableMedian$day)[dayMedVec])x=tableMedian[tableMedian$day==dayMed,]p=ggplot(x,aes(x=AGE,y=SCORES))+geom_bar(stat=\"identity\",alpha=1)print(p)}"
```

Need a logic such that I grab

`ggstyle(inputFile)`

My approach was to grab everything before

`<-function` as a first vector

and everything between `function()` as a second vector

and combine the two vectors.
However none of that worked :(

Any suggestion?
also my approach might be wrong:(

Comment: My Expected o/p is ggstyle(inputFile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `gsub` to match the substring that we want to delete and replace it with `''`

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]+function|\\{.*", "", longString)
#[1] "ggstyle(inputFile)"
```

Or capture the strings as a group and replace it with the backreference

```
sub("^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:punct:]]+[[:alpha:]]+([^)]+\\)).*", "\\1\\2", longString)
#[1] "ggstyle(inputFile)"
```

Comment: Wow :)
Thanks a ton